# Erlang function clause with guards efficiency? Is it O(n)?

Tags: erlang

Working with protobuf (PROTOcol BUFfer by Google), I need "goto" a piece of logic to handle a corresponding type of message received. There should be many types of messages, with regard to this I came up with two methods of "goto":

1. by function clause with guard that matches the message_type;
2. setting up a ETS using the message_type as the key, then apply(Module, Fun) where Module and Fun are stored in the ETS.

Now I suspect #1 is O(n) due to complicated guards being involved, whereas looking up ETS O(1) undoubtedly.

What do you say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like **premature optimization**. Optimization should definitely happen after you profiled your code. I strongly advise that you favor code maintenance over optimization until the code is deemed too slow, and I personally would choose **function clauses** for this reason.

Nevertheless, you might enjoy the Efficency Guide and specially the [**chapter on function clauses**](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/functions.html). In many cases, they are optimized by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

And what makes you think that `apply` would not have O(n) efficiency?  And what is your constant cost with each implementation?

First of all, in your case `n` is more or less constant (number of function or cases).  So you should not compare big O notations, but actual costs around given `n`.

It is most visible with O(1), which basically says that your cost doesn't grow with problem size; but it does not say that you don't have any const, or your cost is small.  Still, you could be using more resources than O(n) form n smaller than 1000.

In the end what you should look at is actual data.  Try to benchmark both solutions, and see which one seems faster.  Or even better, use simple one, and start worry after you performance drop.  Just don't try to fix things that don't have to be fixed.

Personally I would state that function clause will be faster.  With ETS you could have some issues with concurrent reads in between multiple processes (even with dirty reads enabled).